# Clipboard "copy" selection gone when autosizing VBA button?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

**I´m puzzled that Excel throws away the clipboard "copy" selection for no (obvious) reason when creating an auto-sized button.**

Consider this simple selection change handler:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim P As Button: Set P = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1, 1, 100, 100)
End Sub
```

This simple creates a dumb button on the top left corner of the sheet on every cell selection change.

If you press Ctrl-C in any cell (no matter if it´s empty or not), the cell will have this nice border indicating that the selection is what will be pasted if you select paste elsewhere.

That border will remain visible even if you navigate around on the sheet.

Now add one line:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Dim P As Button: Set P = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1, 1, 100, 100)
    P.AutoSize = True
End Sub
```

This makes the button(s) autosize themselves. Works fine. But from know on, every selection change will destroy the clipboard "copy" selection.

- **Why? Can I prevent this, or work around it?**

Reproduced with Excel 10 14.0.7116.5000 32-bit :-O

Comment: To work around it don't use `SelectionChange` to do something as dramatic as adding a Button. In fact, avoid this event as much as possible as it slows down your use of Excel (and disables Undo).

Comment: Yeah. Rest assured I have good reasons to stick to this event, and to spitting out buttons from its handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have copied content then you will need to paste it before anything else happens. This is how Excel behaves naturally.

So, in your event, you can Paste the content (to the currently active cell) before Auto-Sizing the button.

```
Dim P As Button

If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
    Me.Paste
End If
Set P = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(1, 1, 100, 100)

'Application.EnableEvents = False
P.AutoSize = True
'Application.EnableEvents = True
```

`EnableEvents` is unnecessary here, but I've included it to indicate how you might prevent an event from triggering a second time. You probably need to work with it at some point.

Comment: I don't want to paste. I only want to create a button without loosing the state that the last Edit, Copy operation created.

Comment: It is the natural behaviour of Excel that the Copy content is lost if something considered substantial happens. I think it would be hard work (and messy) to get around this. Perhaps someone else will advise you.

Comment: So adding a new button is more substantial than switching over to a different sheet? This made sense since adding a button can be considered a change to the spreadsheet, and changing data always undoes the "copy" selection.

Comment: And: Currently, I have an "avoid reentrancy" flag that avoids certain events to be triggered indirectly from my `SelectionChange` handler to re-trigger the `SelectionChange` event. The 'EnableEvents` hint might prove useful here...

Comment: Ok, dismissed the concept. Answer plus comments proved useful, thanks.