# Clipboard in VBA disappears after few steps

Tags: excel, vba, format, clipboard

I have a code that should restore range formatting after applying few step.

```
Sub MyCode()
Sheets("My sheet").ListObjects("My Table").DataBodyRange.Copy
...
refreshing connection and calling function that applies stored formulas to table columns
...
Sheets("My sheet").[A10].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End sub
```

I got error `PasteSpecial` method on range failed
If I paste immediately, it works.

Is it possible to save range formatting as variable?

Comment: Depends what the code in between does. Can you update and provide code in between?

Comment: Indepent of your code in between: Rely on the clipboard as short as possible. You can insert a temporary sheet and copy the formatting to it.

Comment: Well, there is connection refresh (what does not cause problem) but there is my function that applies stored formulas to excel table columns and it does. After this step error occurs, but it has to stay there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clipboard "copy" selection gone when autosizing VBA button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833050/clipboard-copy-selection-gone-when-autosizing-vba-button). Also look [here](https://superuser.com/a/623142)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use variables to store the copy method and use it later. You can set the range to a variable `CopyRange` and use `CopyRange.Copy` to store it and later you can use it as the range was stored in the `CopyRange` and not lost along the way due to other processes running down the line.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CopyDataToTemplate()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim srcWB As Workbook
Dim destWB As Workbook
Dim srcWS As Worksheet
Dim destWS As Worksheet
Dim CopyRange As Variant

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim srcLRow As Long, destLRow As Long

Set destWB = Excel.Workbooks("DOLine_example.xlsx")
Set srcWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set srcWS = srcWB.ActiveSheet
Set destWS = destWB.Sheets("DOLine")

srcLRow = srcWS.Cells(srcWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
destLRow = destWS.Cells(destWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'loop through column 1 to 19
For i = 1 To 19
    For j = 1 To 13
        'loop through columns

            If destWS.Cells(3, i).value = srcWS.Cells(1, j).value Then    
                ' Copy column B to Column D as written in your code above
                Set CopyRange = srcWS.Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(srcLRow, j))
                    CopyRange.Copy
                ' paste columns from one wb to Columns to another wb
                destWS.Cells(destLRow, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=False
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Process completed!", vbInformation
End Sub
```